# TSQL Check for Date difference except for Min Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that selects all messages for a specific user, except for ones in a table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_LA_SelectAllUnreadMessagesForUser]
   @UserID INT = 1
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM Message m              
   WHERE m.ID NOT IN (SELECT mt.MessageID 
                      FROM MessageTracking mt
                      WHERE mt.SubscriberID = @UserID
                     )
     AND m.DateExpires < GETDATE() /* With the other check */
   ORDER BY m.DateCreated DESC
END
```

I need to extend this to not include 'Expired messages'.

There is a `DateExpires` column on the `Message` table, however - for everlasting messages, the `DateExpires` is set to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Is there any way to check if the date is after a certain date, except for when its `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` ?

Comment: Is the expired message check to be done independent of the user ID, or along with the check on user ID i.e. add filtering logic to the inner query or outer?

Comment: The outer query. So `WHERE m.ID NOT IN () AND ....`

Comment: And when yo try to write a query like that, do you get any errors or unexpected results? If so, please share the details.

Comment: I've updated my example to show where my initial date check is. I just need to exclude `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` from the `AND m.DateExpires < GETDATE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Message m              
 WHERE m.ID NOT IN (SELECT mt.MessageID 
                  FROM MessageTracking mt
                  WHERE mt.SubscriberID = @UserID
                 )
 AND (m.DateExpires > GETDATE()) OR (m.DateExpires = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
 ORDER BY m.DateCreated DESC
```

You want to check if the expiry date is after the current date, or if the particular date is equal to your special value.

Answer (score 1):

edit:

```
select *
where ( DateExpires = '19000101' OR DateExpires > getdate() )
```

which wil list any that have a "never expire" condition plus any that expire after the current date/time

Comment: Well, I don't want to get the message if the `DateExpires` is **before** today... However,  everlasting messages have a `DateExpires` of `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` which is always today, but they should still be included.

Comment: I've edited my answer, as long as you exclude 19000101 it should be ok.

Comment: Using an edit of your answer, this is bringing back the results I want `AND ( m.DateExpires = '19000101' OR m.DateExpires > GETDATE() )`

Comment: oh, I get it now... yes that's fine

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Declare @Today = Getdate();

SELECT *
   FROM Message m              
   WHERE m.ID NOT IN (SELECT mt.MessageID 
                      FROM MessageTracking mt
                      WHERE mt.SubscriberID = @UserID
                     )
     AND (m.DateExpires < @Today
        OR m.DateExpires = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') /* With the other check */
   ORDER BY m.DateCreated DESC;
```

I would rather remove the getdate() from the where clause as it may lead to poor performance. Reasons: firstly, getdate() would be calculated for each row and it may also lead to non usgae of index. But please use your own discretion and test results to arrive at a conclusion.